# Android Datepicker return strange values on formating

Tags: java, android, date-formatting

I have problem with date picker. When i select date. I would like to parse it to format d/m/yy. Unfortunatelly it doestn works correctly.
String returned is like

> 7/67/89

```
 private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/m/yy");
public void openDataPicker(View view) {
    clickedTextEdit = (TextInputEditText) view;
    final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    picker = new DatePickerDialog(CreateProfileActivity.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    clickedTextEdit.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
                }
            }, year, month, day);
    picker.show();
}
```

Comment: Tip: try to find more relevant tags for your problem to attract more people who know about it (I added a couple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the correct format.

See this:

```
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"   // Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"                // 010704120856-0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" // 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" // 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
"YYYY-'W'ww-u"                 // 2001-W27-3
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z" // 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"             // Wed, Jul 4, '01
"h:mm a"                       // 12:08 PM
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz"        // 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"K:mm a, z"                    // 0:08 PM, PDT
"yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa" // 02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM``
```

Comment: I'm so stupid.  I used this as reference ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: Did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

Your Format `"d/m/yy"` in `SimpleDateFormat` means:

> d  = the date of the month
>
> m  = minute, **NOT MONTH**
>
> yy = Year

the format you need is **dd/MM/yy**

More formats you can see here on [**Android SimpleDateFormat Page**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#examples).